# Gekko(python) for lap time optimization

Tags: python, gekko, control-theory, pid-controller

I was wondering if it was a good idea to use Gekko to solve a lap time optimization:
finding the optimal path on a track to minimize total time by controlling the steering angle and the power output.

I'm fairly new to optimal control problem so if you had pointers on how to start that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The bicycle optimal trajectory problem is possible in Gekko. I recommend that you start by working out simple benchmark problems and then take a staged approach (1D to 3D) to building your application. Also, if the authors are willing to share their model, it is often easier to replicate and extend their results. Here are some links to help you get started or see what is possible with a complex trajectory optimization problem (HALE aircraft).

Example problems

- Introductory [Optimal Control Benchmark Problems](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MoreDynamicOptimizationBenchmarks) with the [minimized final time](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime).

[image]

- [Energy optimization](https://apm.byu.edu/prism/uploads/Members/2018_hale_martin.pdf) for HALE aircraft trajectory optimization ([source code](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/hale-trajectory)).

[image: Inverted Pendulum]

- [Inverted Pendulum](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/InvertedPendulum)

There is also the [machine learning and dynamic optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do) that is freely available online if you need additional help getting started.